# Tomcat 7 SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors after add spring-data-jpa to dependency in pom

Tags: spring-mvc, annotations, tomcat7, spring-data-jpa, spring-orm

I have a spring rest app.It is configured with annotations.

When I add spring-data-jpa dependency the application is falling with error on Tomcat 7(jdk 1.7):

```
Jun 22, 2015 5:05:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/springRest-1.1.war
Jun 22, 2015 5:05:19 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/springRest-1.1] startup failed due to previous errors
```

I add logging.properties file to WEB-INF/classes:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

But I didn't catch any additional info into log.

My source code:

MyWebApplicationInitializer.java:

```
import upc.ua.springrest.config.WebConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class MyWebApplicationInitializer extends  AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return null;
}

protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{WebConfiguration.class};
}

protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
}
```

}

WebConfiguration.java:

```
package upc.ua.springrest.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "upc.ua.springrest")
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


}
```

HelloWorldController.java:

```
package upc.ua.springrest.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloWorldController {

    @RequestMapping("/helloWorld")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "dataSource.toString()";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String root() {
        return "Hello, Alex!";
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>upc.ua</groupId>
    <artifactId>springRest</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springRest</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed version of jdk in pom:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Now. It is work fine.

Comment: what was the issue??